# Python 3 SMTP aiosmtpd proxy/relay

Tags: python, smtplib, aiosmtpd

I am trying to make an open SMTP relay using the new `aiosmtpd` library that replaces `smtpd`. The program below instantiates a `Proxy` handler that is passed onto the mail controller, which is started afterwards in the background. A message is then created with a standard `smtplib` client that connects to the relay.

All is good until the SMTP conversation between the client and the relay ends with the message never leaving the relay. The relay never replies with a `250 OK\r\n` and a `ctrl+c` shows that `sendmail` is waiting for a reply.

Any ideas? Is the script missing something?

**Edit**: `mail.example.com` is only an example server. An `smtpd DebuggingServer` prints nothing upon execution of the script with `relay = aiosmtpd.handlers.Proxy("localhost", 1025)`.

```
$ python3.6 -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer -d localhost:1025
DebuggingServer started at Fri Apr  7 18:41:09 2017
    Local addr: ('localhost', 1025)
    Remote addr:('localhost', 25)
...nothing printed out...
```

Script:

```
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging, Proxy
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from smtplib import SMTP

# relay = aiosmtpd.handlers.Debugging()
relay = aiosmtpd.handlers.Proxy("localhost", 1025)
# relay = aiosmtpd.handlers.Proxy("mail.example.com", 25)
controller = Controller(relay)
controller.start()
print(controller, controller.hostname, controller.port)

input("ready... press enter to continue")

print("creating SMTP with debug")
client = SMTP()
client.set_debuglevel(1)
print("connecting to the SMTP server")
client.connect(controller.hostname, controller.port)

print("sending message")
client.sendmail('alice@example.com',
                ['bob@example.com'], """\
From: Alice <alice@example.com>
To: Bob <bob@example.com>
Subject: Title

Body.
""")

print("stopping controller")
controller.stop()
print("checking if controller really stopped")
client.connect(controller.hostname, controller.port)
```

Here is the output of the script:

```
 $ python3.6 relay.py
<aiosmtpd.controller.Controller object at 0x10199f710> ::0 8025
ready... press enter to continue
creating SMTP with debug
connecting to the SMTP server
connect: ('::0', 8025)
connect: to ('::0', 8025) None
reply: b'220 localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4'
connect: b'localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4'
sending message
send: 'ehlo localhost\r\n'
reply: b'250-localhost\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 33554432\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'localhost\nSIZE 33554432\n8BITMIME\nHELP'
send: 'mail FROM:<alice@example.com> size=85\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'rcpt TO:<bob@example.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
data: (354, b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: b'From: Alice <alice@example.com>\r\nTo: Bob <bob@example.com>\r\nSubject: Title\r\n\r\nBody.\r\n.\r\n'

...nothing happens at this point...

^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "relay.py", line 49, in <module>
    """)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 881, in sendmail
    (code, resp) = self.data(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 568, in data
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 386, in getreply
    line = self.file.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

For comparison, here is the output using the debug handler:

```
 $ python3.6 relay.py
<aiosmtpd.controller.Controller object at 0x10189f710> ::0 8025
ready... press enter to continue
creating SMTP with debug
connecting to the SMTP server
connect: ('::0', 8025)
connect: to ('::0', 8025) None
reply: b'220 localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4'
connect: b'localhost Python SMTP 1.0a4'
sending message
send: 'ehlo localhost\r\n'
reply: b'250-localhost\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 33554432\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'localhost\nSIZE 33554432\n8BITMIME\nHELP'
send: 'mail FROM:<alice@example.com> size=85\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'rcpt TO:<bob@example.com>\r\n'
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: b'354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>'
data: (354, b'End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>')
send: b'From: Alice <alice@example.com>\r\nTo: Bob <bob@example.com>\r\nSubject: Title\r\n\r\nBody.\r\n.\r\n'
---------- MESSAGE FOLLOWS ----------
mail options: ['SIZE=85']
rcpt options: []

From: Alice <alice@example.com>
To: Bob <bob@example.com>
Subject: Title
X-Peer: ('::1', 64397, 0, 0)

Body.
------------ END MESSAGE ------------
reply: b'250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'OK'
data: (250, b'OK')
stopping controller
checking if controller really stopped
connect: ('::0', 8025)
connect: to ('::0', 8025) None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "relay.py", line 51, in <module>
    client.connect(controller.hostname, controller.port)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 722, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Comment: I have no iosmtpd here, but all happens like aiosmtpd failed to send a `250 Ok\r\n` after the reception of the message. I assume that as you started it as a relay to  mail.example.com:20 it may try to contact the relay host and probably fails. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Did not notice the missing `250 OK\r\n`. The goal is to make an open relay that just forwards messages sent by SMTP clients to the provided destination SMTP server. The same behavior also happens for email servers besides the exemplified `mail.example.com`.

Comment: In case of connection error, should not the proxy raise an exception and/or at least have the delivery function return control to the main application?

Comment: Did you try to relay to a server for which you know that it will accept the mail, a smtpd DebuggingServer for example?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Just tried that. The behavior does not change. Updated the question with this.

Comment: Hope just a typo, but the line for localhost:1025 is the commented one, and the shown script tries to connect to example.com...

Comment: It is not a typo. I tried to connect to `localhost` during test. Changed the commented line for better comprehension.

Comment: Could install aiosmtpd 1.0a5. With your script I get an error *inside iosmtpd*. Looks like it is still in alpha (no precision on level at pypi). If you want to try it, I think that you must be ready to use it at source level and do some debugging on it. Good luck with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: The bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/pull/74) in aiosmtpd 1.0b1, so an upgrade should resolve the issue.

In aiosmtpd 1.0a4, an uncaught exception in `Proxy.handle_DATA` (using `data` as a str instead of bytes) causes the asyncio task to stop, but the exception is never propagated.

If you upgrade to 1.0a5 you'll get the exception printed properly: "Error: (TypeError) cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object". The problem is that as of 1.0a5, `Proxy` in aiosmtpd is designed for use in a Controller subclass that sets `decode_data=True` on the `aiosmtpd.smtp.SMTP` object, but by default, `decode_data=False` which causes the error. (In my opinion `Proxy` should be changed to work with `decode_data=False`, so I've opened [PR #74](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiosmtpd/pull/74).)

Thus, to use Proxy in aiosmtpd 1.0a4 or 1.0a5 you need to copy and use the `UTF8Controller` subclass from `aiosmtpd/tests/test_handlers.py`. I've tested the following script with both 1.0a4 and 1.0a5:

```
from aiosmtpd.handlers import Debugging, Proxy
from aiosmtpd.controller import Controller
from aiosmtpd.smtp import SMTP as SMTPServer
from smtplib import SMTP as SMTPClient

class UTF8Controller(Controller):
    def factory(self):
        return SMTPServer(self.handler, decode_data=True)

# relay = Debugging()
relay = Proxy("localhost", 1025)
# relay = Proxy("mail.example.com", 25)
controller = UTF8Controller(relay)
controller.start()
print(controller, controller.hostname, controller.port)

input("ready... press enter to continue")

print("creating SMTP with debug")
client = SMTPClient()
client.set_debuglevel(1)
print("connecting to the SMTP server")
client.connect(controller.hostname, controller.port)

print("sending message")
client.sendmail('alice@example.com',
                ['bob@example.com'], """\
From: Alice <alice@example.com>
To: Bob <bob@example.com>
Subject: Title

Body.
""")

print("stopping controller")
controller.stop()
print("checking if controller really stopped")
client.connect(controller.hostname, controller.port)
```

Comment: This solution does sort out the issue. Hopefully the pull request on GitHub will make it through.

Comment: The pull request was merged for 1.0b1, so your original code now works unmodified with aiosmtpd.